# App Engine Service Deployment Stopped Working on Known Good Version

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

We have a service hosted in gcloud that is not actively developed and we have not deployed for a few weeks.
On deployment we now get the error `ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): unorderable types: NoneType() > int()` and the deployment fails.
We get the exact same results even if we run the last deployed version through CI.

This is my `app.yaml`

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
threadsafe: true
service: myapp
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  service_name: myapp
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: {{AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: {{AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
  AWS_REGION: eu-west-1
```

This is very unclear to me as it's not obvious what the deployment would need ordering. Is there something I am missing in interperating this error message?

Comment: Suggestion. Reboot your system. Then run `gcloud components update`. Then try the command again. I do not see anything obvious in your deployment.

Comment: Do you have a `default` GAE service deployed in the same project?

Comment: We do have a default service for the project @Dan

Comment: The packages are up to date @John. I had wondered if there was something wrong in the new version, but I'm sure I would have seen something here if that were the case.

Comment: We are seeing the exact same issue in an almost identical scenario.  @Max - did you find a cause,resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have Python 3.5 installed on the same build agent. The gcloud SDK has a dependency of Python 2.7, also advisable to set the `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` environment variable to the path of your Python 2.7 installation location.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that worked for me:

1. Instead of `gcloud app deploy ...` try `gcloud beta app deploy ...`

   - You may be prompted to install the beta components (allow this)
2. If adding 'beta' results in a successful deployment, try again without it.

It seems like something was corrupt and using the 'beta' deployment command un-corrupted things. Your mileage may vary.